# Is there a way to alter the form action attribute with CSS only, or is there an alternative to JavaScript and server-side script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, security

First of all, I don’t have access to the forms mark-up or server-side script due to being on a proprietary system. I did remove attributes with jQuery , and allow for my user action to replace this data along with replacing the Submit button. The problem is, a bot/spider/crawler (the reason I am doing this) can go to my site with JavaScript disabled and bypass this filter. So I am looking for an alternative way to “break” the form until they confirm they are human. The captcha seems to be useless.

I would show the jQuery and plug-in, but it might be irrelevant as I am looking for a JavaScript alternative and server-side script alternative. If I can remove the data with an alternative, I can easily replace with the jQuery, as it is functional and not the issue.

This is the basic of what is being removed/replaced....

```
$('form.ProductReviewForm').attr('action', '')
    .attr('method', '');
```

then replacing them after the slide feature.

**UPDATE:** I was able to get zero bot posts today with the use of....

```
(function($){
$('form.ProductReviewForm').attr('action', '')
    .attr('method', '');
$(document).bind( "mousemove keypress", function () {
    $('form.ProductReviewForm').attr('action', 'http://www.diabeteshealthsupplies.com/postreview.php')
        .attr('method', 'post');
});
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, we are only fixing the attributes with mousemove or keypress. Something the user will have to do, but not the bots.

Comment: CSS cannot change content, it can only hide it.

Comment: Just add a robots.txt file and deny access to that URL.

Comment: @iMoses But I want to allow analytic bots. Is there a way to do this without inadvertently denying good bots?

Comment: @Shane so you're saying that some bot is being able to skip the re-captcha?

Comment: Maybe there's something I don't know, but what information could an analytic bot get from your form action? Mostly it will take care to web crawlers which can imitate a user using JS.

Comment: @iMoses You are right, I am referencing crawlers or spiders I believe rather than a bot. The point is to stop them from submitting data to my reviews.

Comment: @Shane if the bot is able to consistently bypass the Captcha then you are probably using it incorrectly.

Comment: @pollirrata I am getting spam from this form. Not sure how they are doing it except that they are breaking through re-captcha and bypassing my slide button somehow.

Comment: Your JS and your server don't check the captcha at all.. I was able to submit the form without it.

Comment: @iMoses actually your data never got submitted to my database and I can not repeat this? What are you seeing?

Comment: @ExplosionPills this is a proprietary use of captcha we have no control over. And, your statement is not exactly true, there is a lot if information about captcha not being full proof.